# Передача массива в функцию используя ссылку

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, ссылки

Есть массив, состоящий из 3-х элементов. Нужно передать массив в функцию(которая посчитает сумму элементов) тремя разными способами.
Как передавать указателем и просто аргументом(да, я понимаю что это тоже указатель) я понимаю, но как использовать ссылку?

```
    #include <iostream>

int sum1(int arr[])
{
    int sumArr = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        sumArr += arr[i];
    }
    return sumArr;
}

int sum2(int* arr)
{
    int sumArr = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        sumArr += *(arr + 1);
    }
    return sumArr;
}

int sum3(int &arr)
{
    int sumArr = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        ???
    }
    return sumArr;
}
```

Comment: лично я, не понел, что значит передать **просто аргументом**

Comment: `int arr[]` и `int* arr` это одно и то же, а не 2 разных способа

Comment: указатель на массив выглядит так: `Type (*arr)[3]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Вашем случае нужно написать так: `int sum3(int (&arr)[3])`. В таком подходе есть недостаток: ваша функция может принимать только массивы длиной в три элемента.
Обращение к элементам такое же, как и в функции `sum1`

```cpp
int sum3(int (&arr)[3])
{
    int sumArr = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        sumArr += arr[i];
    }
    return sumArr;
}
```

PS. Ваши функции не изменяют массив, поэтому имеет смысл обьявлять параметр `arr` как `const`.

---

Так же можно написать шаблонную функцию:

```cpp
template<typename Type, size_t N>
Type sum(Type (&arr)[N])
{
    Type sumArr {};

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        sumArr += arr[i];
    }
    return sumArr;
}
```

Comment: Это ладно, но как мне обратиться к самим элементам, чтобы сложить их?

Comment: @DanilaPtuha обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Фигня, конечно, но коду из вопроса соответствует именно она:

```
sumArr += (&arr)[i];
```

```
sumArr += *(&arr + i);
```